# Using Laravel API Resource to get events in fullcalendar

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use Laravel API + Vue to render events in FullCalendar.

In Vue I have the code:

```
<FullCalendar
      ref="fullCalendar"
      class="calendar"
      default-view="dayGridMonth"
      :header="{
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,next today',
      }"
      :plugins="calendarPlugins"
      :weekends="calendarWeekends"
      :events="calendarEvents"
      locale="it"
      :firstDay="1"
      @dateClick="handleDateClick"
      @eventClick="handleEventEdit"
/> 
...
components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
data: function() {
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [
        dayGridPlugin,
        interactionPlugin,
      ],
      editable: true,
      calendarWeekends: true,
      calendarEvents: this.elist, 
      eventFormVisible: false,
      elist: [],
    };
  },
...
created() {
    this.getElist();
  },
methods: {
      async getElist() {
      this.Equery.user_id = this.userId;
      this.elist = await eventResource.list(this.Equery); // http://mysite.test/api/events?user_id=1
      this.elist = this.elist.data;
    },
...
```

API response seems correct:

```
{"data":[{"id":2,"user_id":1,"job_id":null,"job":"2018-090-01","title":"2018-090-01 : 2","hours":2,"start":"2019-11-06T00:00:00+0000","end":"2019-11-06T00:00:00+0000"},{"id":3,"user_id":1,"job_id":null,"job":"2018-090-01","title":"2018-090-01 : 1","hours":1,"start":"2019-11-29T00:00:00+0000","end":"2019-11-29T00:00:00+0000"}]}
```

but events are not loaded

For debug purpose I try with:

```
calendarEvents: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
```

and it works!
I can't find the error, I need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't initialize a data property by referencing another data property. `calendarEvents: this.elist` is incorrect. Instead, initialize it as an empty array and assign to it in the `created` method of the component.

Comment: Opsss. Sorry, I'm a beginner. Thanks alot